# Midrash on children and the letter shapes?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minor-katan-child, midrash, aleph-bet-letters, agada-stories-legends

I've heard about a midrash that discusses a day when little children took over the study hall and, by interpreting the shapes of the Hebrew letters, articulated many of Judaism's most powerful religious messages.

Anyone know where the midrash is? Is there a form of it in the Gemara?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the Gemara on [Shabbos 104a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=104&format=pdf).

> The Rabbis told R. Joshua b. Levi: Children have come to the Beth
> Hamidrash and said things the like of which was not said even in the
> days of Joshua the son of Nun. [Thus:] alef Beth [means] ‘learn wisdom
> [alef Binah];Gimmel Daleth, show kindness to the Poor [Gemol Dallim].
> Why is the foot of the Gimmel stretched toward the Daleth? Because it
> is fitting for the benevolent to run after [seek out] the poor. And
> why is the roof of the Daleth stretched out toward the Gimmel?
> Because he [the poor] must make himself available to him...
>
> iTalmud app translation

Also, I don't think they're talking about real children, but rather, younger generations that discover new hidden meanings in the Torah, which weren't taught in the traditional oral-torah of previous generations.